# Need help to loop through and extract variable from a object within an array

Tags: node.js, google-maps, coordinates

first of all, I´m a noobie to say at least in programming, and this is actually my first project. But now i seem to be stuck and need some help. :)

Mission:

Im trying to grab the `lat` and `lon` variables from the MQTT stream, and return it like this

```
[{"lat":54.9619349,"lng":-1.6003813},{"lat":54.9656694,"lng":-1.5239833},{"lat":54.9696456,"lng":-1.5069755},{"lat":54.9378907,"lng":-1.5273729}]
```

This is how far i got:

```
var msg.payload = {"id":10,"created":"2014-05-24T07:31:05","location":{"disposition":"mobile","waypoints":[
{"at":"Friday","lat":43.64,"lon":10.73,"ele":"15"},{"at":"Saturday","lat":43.68,"lon":10.78,"ele":"26"},{"at":"Monday","lat":43.72,"lon":10.83,"ele":"43"},{"at":"Tuesday","lat":43.41,"lon":10.36,"ele":"98"}]}};

for (var i = 0, l = msg.payload.location.waypoints.length; i < l; i++) {
    var obj = msg.payload.location.waypoints[i];

    return obj
}
```

This just gives me the first object like this and not an array like above:

```
{"at":"Friday","lat":43.64,"lon":10.73,"ele":"15"}
```

Confused! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make the variable obj into a array, and push JSON Objects with lat & lon as keys with its respective values into the array.

```
var obj = [];
for (var i = 0, l = msg.payload.location.waypoints.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj.push({
        "lat" : msg.payload.location.waypoints[i].lat,
        "lon" : msg.payload.location.waypoints[i].lon
    })

    return obj
}
```

Comment: Looks better.. But it still its just returning one set of waypoints:


`var obj = [];
for (var i = 0, l = msg.payload.location.waypoints.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj.push({
        "lat" : msg.payload.location.waypoints[i].lat,
        "lng" : msg.payload.location.waypoints[i].lon
    })

    msg.payload = obj;
    return msg
}`

Returns:

`(Object) { "topic": "API-KEY/v2/feeds/#######.json?duration=24hours", "payload": [ { "lat": 39.653055555555554, "lng": 6.637777777777778 } ], "qos": 0, "retain": true }`

Comment: Thats strange, can you put a console.log right after the loop and print the contents of obj.

Comment: Funny, your solution works. Tested it in jsfiddle.. 
Im using node-red and but this within a function node which basically is a js. hmm, back to square one.. :)